# Not mapped abstract class in the middle of TPT hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

I've have these entities in Table-Per-Type hierarchy as a part of my model:

```
// mapped to table "Templates"
public abstract class Template {}

// not mapped, and must not be mapped
public abstract class TextualTemplate : Template {}

// mapped to table "TextTemplates"
public class TextTemplate : TextualTemplate {}

// mapped to table "TextFieldTemplates"
public class TextFieldTemplate : TextualTemplate {}
```

Mappings are set by number of `EntityTypeConfiguration` descendants.
Mappings for `TextTemplate` and `TextFieldTemplate` contain explicit mapping expressions for properties, inherited from `TextualTemplate`, because tables in database contains appropriate fields, but not for properties, inherited from `Template`.

When I'm trying to load `Template`s, I'm getting an error like:

> Invalid column name `column_from_TextualTemplate_entity_1`
>   ...
>   Invalid column name `column_from_TextualTemplate_entity_n`
>   Invalid column name `Discriminator`

I've looked into a query, which is being sent to a database, and it looks like EF assumes, that either `TextualTemplate` is mapped, or it tries to find these columns in `Templates` table.

I know, that I can throw away `TextualTemplate` class, and duplicate properties in `TextTemplate` and `TextFieldTemplate` respectively, but this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there any way to tell EF, that these columns should be found in tables for inherited types?

Comment: It looks like what you really want is Table per Concrete Type, but not Table per Type

Comment: @DixonD: not really. Template contains number of properties, which are mapped to a base type's table. There are much more descendants for Template class, and all them fit TPT. The question contains just a branch of inheritance tree. The only thing I want is to avoid duplication of several properties in this branch at conceptual model level (I can't change database structure to make a separate table for TextualTemplate, but I know, that is a way to go too).

Comment: Does this help ?~http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125424/sales-order-domain-model-with-entity-framework/126788?noredirect=1#comment237014_126788